# Generating binary strings in order using recursion

Tags: javascript

Hello below function generates the binary strings of a given length, but has one little issue - each string is generated in reverse order(*the second number is 100 instead of 001*). I've been trying to fix this w/o using *split-reverse-join*. Any ideas ?

```js
document.write(generateBinaryStringsOfLength(3).join("<br>"));

function generateBinaryStringsOfLength(n) {
  var arr = [];
  populate_arr(n, "");

  function populate_arr(n, str) {
    if (str.length == n) {
      //arr.push(str.split("").reverse().join(""));
      arr.push(str);
    } else {
      populate_arr(n, "0" + str);
      populate_arr(n, "1" + str);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to reverse the order in which you pass the `str` parameter inside the `populate_arr()` function

## these two lines

```
      populate_arr(n, "0" + str );
      populate_arr(n, "1" + str );
```

## should be

```
      populate_arr(n, str + "0");
      populate_arr(n, str + "1");
```

```js
document.write(generateBinaryStringsOfLength(3).join("<br>"));

function generateBinaryStringsOfLength(n) {
  var arr = [];
  populate_arr(n, "");

  function populate_arr(n, str) {
    if (str.length == n) {
      //arr.push(str.split("").reverse().join(""));
      arr.push(str);
    } else {
      populate_arr(n, str + "0");
      populate_arr(n, str + "1");
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion. Its better to highlight the part you have changed. I had to read line by line, both your's and OP's code to get it. It would easier for everyone, I guess

Comment: Ahh awesome! Ty :) can't help feeling bad for not seeing this myself though -.-

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks for the advice. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

you're adding strings in the wrong order

```
a = "hi "
b = a + "bill!"
c = "Aditya, " + a
console.log(b);
// "hi bill!"
console.log(c);
// "Aditya, hi"
```

fixed code:

```js
document.write(generateBinaryStringsOfLength(3).join("<br>"));

function generateBinaryStringsOfLength(n) {
  var arr = [];
  populate_arr(n, "");

  function populate_arr(n, str) {
    if (str.length == n) {
      //arr.push(str.split("").reverse().join(""));
      arr.push(str);
    } else {
      populate_arr(n, str + "0");
      populate_arr(n, str + "1");
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your implementation then you can return the resulting array with arr.sort()

```js
document.write(generateBinaryStringsOfLength(3).join("<br>"));

function generateBinaryStringsOfLength(n) {
  var arr = [];
  populate_arr(n, "");

  function populate_arr(n, str) {
    if (str.length == n) {
      //arr.push(str.split("").reverse().join(""));
      console.log(arr);
      arr.push(str);
    } else {
      populate_arr(n, "0" + str);
      populate_arr(n, "1" + str);
    }
  }
  return arr.sort();
}
```

Hope this helps!